# Property Grid for Cocoa

Tags: c#, objective-c, cocoa, reflection, propertygrid

I didn't find anything similar to .NET PropertyGrid class in Cocoa, so I started to write my own version.
I use information from runtime to get properties of object:

```
Class reflectedClass = [reflectedObject class];
uint propertyCount = 0U;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(reflectedClass, 
                                                     &propertyCount);
```

And this for getting/setting values in NSTableView:

```
- (NSString *)propertyNameAtIndex:(int)index
{
    return (NSString *)[cachedPropertyNames objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (id)propertyValueAtIndex:(int)index
{
    return [reflectedObject valueForKey:[self propertyNameAtIndex:index]];
}

- (void)setPropertyValue:(id)value atIndex:(int)index
{
    [reflectedObject setValue:value forKey:[self propertyNameAtIndex:index]];
}
```

For syncing updates with `reflectedObject` is used basic KVO:

```
[reflectedObject addObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:propertyName
                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | 
                             NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                     context:NULL];
```

This solution works, but I have two problems that I need to fix:

1. I need to simulate somehow .NET attributes, so I can choose right editor for property.
   Text boxes is not good for all situations.
2. Different cell editor for each row, so for booleans checkboxes, for strings textboxes, etc.

I am still beginner in Cocoa so sorry if I am asking for something really basic.

**UPDATE:** I need something like this (picture from Xcode->Get Info->Build):

[PropertyGridCocoa http://www.adorior.cz/Images/PropertyGridCocoa.png](http://www.adorior.cz/Images/PropertyGridCocoa.png)

Comment: What's a property grid, and how is it better than just creating the right controls for the model in IB?

Comment: Property grid is similar to inspector in IB, like in IB it allows to change properties of any object. In .NET it gets properties of any object via reflection, it is good tool for prototyping UI.

You can see something about it at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa has no such view built in to the framework. If no-one else has created one and released it as open source, you will need to create one from the ground up.

It's probably easier to hand-craft a UI that matches the underlying model.

Comment: I want to create it on the fly from runtime.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Like I said, no such thing exists in Cocoa, so you'll have to either find an open-source one that someone already made or make one yourself.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time. I will try to write it on my own.